# Создание подключения к Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

Есть проблема с созданием подключения к Oracle. Создаётся переменная:

```
private OracleConnection conn;
```

Потом подключается:

```
conn = new OracleConnection(connection_string);
```

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'Инициализатор типа
>   "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection" выдал исключение.'

Подключение идёт с помощью библиотеки `using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;`
Не разу с ней не работал, обычно использую `using System.Data.OracleClient`
Что у меня не так подскажите пожалуйста? connectionstring верный.

Comment: А исключение то какое?

Comment: @lDrakonl вот текст ошибки. `The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client.`

Comment: @lDrakonl я так понимаю нужно заменить DataAccess.Client на OracleClient?

Comment: Андрей, соорудите мини пример кода, который вызывает ошибку и добавьте его к вопросу. Или скажите, чем мой ответ вам не подходит

Comment: Укажите в вопросе какая используется версия клиента и ODP.Net

Comment: @defaultlocale ODP.net не знаю где посмотреть, если подскажите погляжу, версия оракла 11g

Comment: Тут еще понадобится указать битность (x32/x86 или x64) как для клиента оракла так и для ODP (посмотрите версию в свойствах библиотеки `DataAccess`)

Answer (score 1):

Соединение с Oracle и запрос.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace HelloWorld2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oracleConnectionString = "Data Source=DEV_V;User id=snapshoter;Password=snapshoter;";      
            OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString);
            try
            {   // откроем соединение
                connection.Open(); 

                OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand();
                oracleCommand.Connection = connection;

                // запрос на создание снапшота. У пользователя должны быть необходимые права
                oracleCommand.CommandText = "select 1 as num from dual";

                OracleDataReader reader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();            
                int num = 0;                
                //получим результат запроса
                num = reader.GetInt32(0);
                Console.WriteLine("num = " + num);

            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            { 
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```